# Visual Studio IDE 2022 (C#) - Auto-complete of parentheses is broken

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2022

I'm using `Visual Studio IDE` 2022, Parentheses completion is not working correctly. For example, I want to write:

```
Foo(Boo());
```

but result is:

```
Foo(Boo(); - one brace is missing.
```

[image]

I have checked and unchecked "Automatic brace completion" but it does not help.

By the way `VSCode` does this job correctly:

[image]

If you want this problem to be solved  please vote here: [Autocompleteofparenthesesisbroken](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Matching-a-closing-brace-in-Visual-Studi/1626691)

Comment: Shouldn’t it not work if there are missing brackets? Why is it missing after selecting automatic completion of parentheses? Did you try to reset vs or restart vs?

Comment: yes, I did it but it did not helped

Comment: Please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here. What is Boo()?

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. Have you installed some smart reminder extensions?

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT
https://i.imgur.com/vAm7idv.gif

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT
It does not depends on extensions. Now I have check on other computer where no extensions are installed, only Visual studio 2019. seems it is an old problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it is an old problem because the same problem was with [C++](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/auto-complete-of-parentheses-is-broken/43655).
I think for C++ the problem was solved but `C#` was forgotten.

If you want this problem to be solved for `C#` in `Visual Studio IDE` please vote here:
[Autocompleteofparenthesesisbroken](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Matching-a-closing-brace-in-Visual-Studi/1626691)